# Request Timeout Umbraco Azure via Ajax

Tags: c#, .net, azure, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a script that creates an entry in the Media page in Umbraco. The idea is that I upload the videos in the server via FTP. Now I have a button that I will click where in turn will call an API. This API will run a script that will create a media entry programmatically after creating it will delete that file. Using this method I can create a media in Umbraco even with large files. Now I'm having a timeout issue when the file is really big. Are there any workaround for this? I'm using Azure Web App Service for my application. How do I solve this timeout issue?

Below is my code

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads");

foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{

    using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string mediaType = Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File;
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

        if (ext == ".jpg" || ext== ".png" || ext == ".gif" || ext == ".jpeg") {
            mediaType = Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.Image;
        }

        IMedia media = Services.MediaService.CreateMedia(filename, Constants.System.Root, mediaType);
        media.SetValue("umbracoFile", filename, stream);
        Services.MediaService.Save(media);
        media = null;
    }

    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

Comment: `<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<!--<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />-->
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="2097151" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100"/>
</system.web>`

Comment: `<system.webServer> 
<security>
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2072576000"/> 
</requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>`

Comment: You can configure it in web.config. My suggestion set the max size of file is 2G, you can set higher. Looking forward to your test results.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using azure, I would [configure Umbraco to use blobstorage](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Extending/FileSystemProviders/Azure-Blob-Storage/) then the upload can be done to blobstorage instead of locale app instance. Azure web instances are limited in memory usage over time. So uploading big files to your azure web app might be a bad idea anyways.

Second and easy solution, if it happens only once: upload a small file in umbraco and then overwrite the file on disk with FTP.

Third solution: consider services like youtube or vimeo as they handle all encoding for all different browsers & bandwidth.

If you consider allowing to upload big files in your web.config.
Do not change the `maxAllowedContentLength` without thinking twice as this will increase potentional DoS attacks. If it is really the only solution, only allow this on the necessary paths (eg your /umbraco/ folder)